# asp.net membership ResetPassword does not work

Tags: asp.net, hash, membership, reset-password

when i want to use `ResetPassword` method in vb.net or c# , it can not reset password and make an exeption that say : "The password-answer supplied is wrong".
i think it is caused by hashing system and machine code of hash and salt.
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

add following attribute to your membership cofig section in your Web.Config file.

```
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

full example

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SqlServices" 
             connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial 
             Catalog=aspnetdb;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <membership 
             defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
             userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
             <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />
                <add name="SqlProvider"
                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                    connectionStringName="SqlServices"
                    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                    enablePasswordReset="true"
                    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                    passwordFormat="Hashed"
                    applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: but i want to use password question

Comment: did you give question and answer when you created the user with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.createuser.aspx method

Answer (score 0):

I used it in a wrong way, and got the same error, hope helps you too. This is my code:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(c.Username);

if (mu.PasswordQuestion == c.Question)
{
    string pwd = mu.ResetPassword(c.Answer);
    mu.ChangePassword(pwd, c.Password);

    return RedirectToAction("SignIn");
}

else
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Error!";
    return View();
}
```